# Initialization lists in Cython c++ classes

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, cython

In the "experimental_cpp_class_def" functionality where you can write a C++ class in Cython (https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/tests/run/cpp_classes_def.pyx), is there syntax for initialization lists? This seems necessary to control which constructors get called in inherited classes.

### Example

C++ "myclass.h":

```
namespace myclass
{

class MyClass {
      MyClass() { };
      MyClass(int x) { };
};
```

Cython:

```
cdef extern from "myclass.h" namespace "myclass":
    cdef cppclass MyClass:
         MyClass()
         MyClass(int x)

cdef cppclass SubClass(MyClass):
         def __init__(int x):
             # Implicitly calls MyClass::MyClass(), but would like to
             # call MyClass::MyClass(x)            
             pass
```